# Create button for javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to create 2 buttons, 1 to start the script and 1 to stop it.

```
 var timerID = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "script.php",
      context: document.body
    });
  }, 60 * 1000);


  clearInterval(timerID);
```

I have no idea how i would have to call this , this is what i was trying:

```
<button id="id" onClick="timerID();"></button>
```

Comment: As the name already suggests, `timerID` is an ID (a numeric value), not a function. You cannot call it. Have a look at http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html to learn more about functions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to wrap it inside another function:

```
var timerID;
var myTimerFn = function () {
    timerID = setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "script.php",
          context: document.body
        });
    }, 60 * 1000);
};

// call
myTimerFn();
```

Then another function to close it. Or pass a parameter to tell it whether to start or stop.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to start and stop the timer?

```
var timerID ;

function start()
{
    var timerID = setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "script.php",
          context: document.body
        });
    }, 60 * 1000);
}

function stop()
{
    clearTimeout(timerID );
}
```

This is how you would call it:

```
<button id="start" onClick="start();"></button>
<button id="stop" onClick="stop();"></button>
```

For more information about `setInterval` check here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: Somehow this still does not work. The code looks better now but i dont get redirected anywhere after pressing the button

Comment: `$.ajax` does not redirect, it returns a response from the url. you must handle the response in your script. I would suggest broadening your question so that we understand what you're try to achive

Comment: @user3170212 then the error is not in the start/stop machinery, as andrew says

Comment: I added the script i am trying to run. I know i could've done more research in AJAX and Javascript but i have a deadline for school and this is the only part of my project using AJAX...